# First isomorphim theorem $\phi(H) = HN/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Theorem: $\frac{H}{H \cap N} \simeq \frac{HN}{N}$. Define $\phi : H\rightarrow G/N$ by $\phi(h)=hN \ \ \ \forall h \in H$

I'm not sure why the image, $\phi(H) = HN/N$ Can anyone show me why? My book has

$$\phi(h) =\{gN \in G/N  \ | \ gN=hN \ for \ some \ h\in H\}$$
$$ = \{ gN \in G/N \ | g \in HN\} = HN/N$$

But I don't see how and why, $gN= hN\rightarrow g \in HN$

Thanks :D!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the image of $\varphi$ is just the set of classes $\{hN:h\in H\}$. Since $nN=N$ for any $n\in N$, this is the same as $\{hnN:h\in H,n\in N\}$, which is the same as $HN/N$. Tne point is we need to enlarge $H$ a bit, namely add $N$ (since $N$ is normal, $\langle H,N\rangle =HN$); so that $HN/N$ "makes sense", but the set of cosets is just the coset space $H/N$.

Comment: thanks ^_^, I didn't see why N was assumed to be normal, after looking at your comments, the product ,HN is a subgroup because N is normal.

Comment: wait...."The point is we need to enlarge H a bit, namely add N (since N is normal, $<H,N>=HN$" What do you mean by $<H,N>$?? $<H,N> = \{x\in G |\ x=hn \ for \ some \ h\in H \ and \ n\in N\}$

Comment: never saw $<H,N>$ before -_-

Comment: @abe15 The subgroup generated by $H$ and $N$.

Comment: Ooo, that fast! Thank you again, check mark for you ^_^

Comment: "The coset space $H/N$"? $N\not\subset H$

Answer (score 2):

$g = g\cdot 1  \in gN = hN \subset HN$

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to see it: $gN = hN$ means that $\{gn\mid n\in N\}$ and $\{hn\mid n\in N\}$ are the same set. In particular this means (since $1\in N$) that $g1$ is equal to $hn$ for some $n\in N$. But $g1=g$, and $hn\in HN$, so this shows that $g\in HN$.

(This is really the same as @ah11950's answer, but with more words.)